# Gráficos para node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gráfico

Estou desenvolvendo um programa em node.js que gera relatórios em .pdf, com tabelas e gráficos. Estive procurando na internet e achei vários pacotes para gerar esses gráficos, como: d3.js e suas variações.

Mas ainda tenho uma dúvida! Todos eles utilizam uma página web em seus exemplos, e minha aplicação roda apenas para gerar o produto final "relatório.pdf", o que gostaria de saber é, se tem como gerar gráficos dentro do node (server-side), e exportar uma imagem .png ou .jpg?

Se possível gostaria de saber, como isso acontece no código, já que, não se vai utilizar as "tags" do html, que muitos módulos precisam acessar para exibir o gráfico na página?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após uma breve pesquisa, aqui vão algumas opções que encontrei (todos eles exportam os gráficos gerados no **server-side** para pdf diretamente):

[AnyChart](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-NodeJS)

[pdfmake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake)

[ChartJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node)